# Message when running Rspec on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am playing with Rails 5 on Windows 10.

When I run "Rails spec" to run my tests I get the following at the start of it and then my tests run just fine:

```
C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -I'C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.2/lib';'C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-support-3.5.0/lib' 'C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.2/exe/rspec' --pattern 'spec/**{,/*/**}/*_spec.rb'
```

Other that it being a pain to look at it doesn't cause any problems.

But I curious as to what it means, and how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the RSpec library telling you what command it is executing. It is useful for debugging purposes.

You can also run RSpec directly with the `$ rspec` with the appropriate options, and it will not print out that lines (as you are executing RSpec directly).